# Double integral under cycloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate the double integral $\int \int _{S} y dxdy$, where S where S is the (finite) region in the xy-plane bounded by (1) and the curve (2):
$$\\y>0 \space \space \space (1)$$ and the curve $$x=R(t-\sin(t)), y = R(1-\cos(t)), 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi \space \space \space (2)$$.

So i realized that $y = dx/dt, dx = ydt$, so that, in the integral, $\int \int _{S} y^2 dt dy = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int _{0}^{ R(1-\cos(t))}y^2 dt dy = \frac{5 \pi R^3}{3}$

But the answer says that it is $5 \pi R^3/2$, so that the factor three in my answer is, apparenttly, wrong.

Someone know where is my error ?

Comment: It seems like the set of $(x,y)$ is a curve, which has measure zero, so the integral would be zero.  Are you sure the region isn’t  something non-zero? Or a one-dimensional integral over $t?$

Comment: My guess would be that original question meant  $x=R(t-\sin t),$ and $0<y<R(1-\cos t).$ This is based on the fact that $R(t-\sin t)$ is positive and increasing from $0$ to $2\pi R.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ops you are right, i will edit it :) thx. Anyway, i can't see where is my error on the solution :(

Comment: "where S is the (finite) region in the $xy$-plane bounded by $y=0$ and the curve $(x,y) = (R(t−\sin(t)), R(1−\cos(t)))$ with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$."

Comment: Well, under this interpretation, it is not true that $y=R(1-\cos t)=dx/dt,$ only that $0<y<dx/dt.$

Comment: You’ve also got the order of your integrals wrong in the last integral. $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi,$ so the integral should be $dy\,dt.$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $dx =R(1-\cos t)\,dt,$but the integral is over $0<y<R(1-\cos t),$ so you can’t make the substitution $dx=y\,dt.$

Instead, the integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{R(1-\cos t)} Ry(1-\cos t)\,dy\,dt$$

You get:

$$\frac{R^3}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} (1-\cos t)^3\,dt$$

The odd terms when expanding $(1-\cos t)^3$ have integral $0.$

So this is equal to:

$$\frac{R^3}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(1+3\cos^2 t)\,dt$$

Now $\cos^2 t = \frac{1+\cos 2t}{2},$ and the integral of $\cos 2t$ is zero, so the result is:

$$\frac{R^3}{2}\cdot 2\pi\frac{5}{2} =\frac{5R^3\pi}{2}$$